# Travelling with two passports, layover in Istanbul

Tags: usa, layovers, dual-nationality, visas-on-arrival, istanbul

I'm travelling from country #1 to country #2. I have passports for both these countries.

I will be using the passport for country #2 on my way there and passport for country #1 when returning. On my way to country #2, I have a layover for 12 hours and wanted to get a visa to explore a bit.

Question is, is it possible to have a visa on my passport #1 even if I'm using my passport for country #2 that leg of the travel?

Answer (score 2):

In this situation, on checking in for your flight, you could show the airline both passports... passport #1 so that they know that you can enter the layover country, and passport #2 so they know that you can enter the destination country.

The airline may not care if you can enter the layover country because they may just assume that you're going to stay in the airport. In that case it may be sufficient to show passport #2 to the airline, and the airline doesn't really have to know that you left the airport using passport #1.

Remember that the airline only cares that they are not going to take you someplace you can't enter, because that would obligate them to fly you back at their expense.